# Printing to Dell V305W from a Mac

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, printer

I bought a Dell V305W Printer/Scanner/Copier/etc... and it works surprisingly well.  But now I've got a mac and there don't seem to be any Mac drivers for this printer on the Dell site.

Do any workarounds exist?
Does Dell even make its own printers or just resell someone else's - perhaps I could get the drivers from the OEM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you are out of luck. [Apparently](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=556011) your printer is not compatible with and does not have drivers for OS X.

Answer (score 1):

The printer is actually a Lexmark.  You can use the OS X drivers for the Lexmark 4600 to print from a Mac.

It works when plugged in via USB, I haven't figured out if you can print wirelessly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a network with a Windows machine available? If so, you can connect the printer to that machine and setup a generic shared printer. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/10369/how-to-share-an-unsupported-for-mac-printer-via-pc/10376#10376) for instructions on how to do this.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  But, I actually asked that question.