# How to share an unsupported (for Mac) printer via PC?

Tags: macos, printer

I am a Mac and I don't support your printer.
Hi, I am a PC and I do.

Per this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/9827/printint-to-dell-v305w-from-a-mac), there aren't any mac drivers for my Dell v305W printer.  Is there anyway, I can share this printer to the Mac via my PC or via a VMWare Fusion Virtual Machine (that's running on my mac the whole time anyway)?  Or do I still need to have a Mac driver no matter what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Mac OS X Hints:
[Print to a non-Mac-supported Windows-connected printer](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20071120194258105&query=printer%2Bwindows)

Comment: This so totally worked.  The link to the actual instructions is here:  http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/winmacprinter/

The instructions are long and somewhat complicated for a non-power-user, but very detailed and filled with screenshots. The whole thing took about good 20-30 minutes to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a generic printer driver to share the printer.  If there is a generic printer driver you can use for your Mac to share from your PC should do the trick.

-JFV