# Citzen Label Printer Drivers for Mac

Tags: mac, drivers, printer, label-printer

Are there any third-party or unofficial [Citizen label printers](http://www.citizen-europe.com/drivers/label.htm) printer drivers which work with Apple/Mac OS?

> Apple® / Mac OS® Drivers: Citizen does not specifically produce drivers for Apple operating system such as Mac OS-X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/10369/how-to-share-an-unsupported-for-mac-printer-via-pc/10376#10376) might be an option for you, if you're on a network with any Windows machines.

Comment: @arathorn Thanks I'll give that a try, if there are no other suggestions.